# ¿Cuál es el máximo valor para "ulimit"? ¿Por qué debo reiniciar la terminal para volver a definirlo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Para cierta aplicación necesito un gran número de archivos abiertos simultáneamente; el límite por defecto de mi SO era 1024, y lo he aumentado utilizando el comando:

```
 ulimit -n 10240
```

Todo ha funcionado bien, pero ¿cuál es el máximo valor que puedo dar a esta cantidad? ¿qué le pasaría al SO si lo aumento arbitrariamente?

Y una segunda pregunta: curiosamente, solo puedo utilizar ese comando una sola vez por sesión del bash, si lo intento lanzar una segunda vez me da un error de permiso (tengo que reiniciar la terminal para cambiarlo de nuevo). ¿Por qué puede ser esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es natural que al fijar el `ulimit` de una sesión éste afecte sólo a esa sesión. Cuando abres un terminal inicias una sesión nueva. Si abres otro terminal, el `ulimit` de la primera sesión no es tomado en cuenta, sino que usa el `ulimit` global.

#### ¿cuál es el máximo valor que puedo dar a esta cantidad?

Es sano guiarse por la salida de

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

Que en mi caso dice 65535

#### ¿Cómo fijar este valor permanentemente sin tener que hacerlo cada vez que abro una terminal?

Para fijar este valor permanentemente, primero editas `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Y añades al final

```
fs.file-max = 65535
```

Luego aplicas esa configuración haciendo `sysctl -p`

Luego editas los límites del sistema con `sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf` añadiendo

```
* soft     nproc          65535    
* hard     nproc          65535   
* soft     nofile         65535   
* hard     nofile         65535
root soft     nproc          65535    
root hard     nproc          65535   
root soft     nofile         65535   
root hard     nofile         65535
```

Los asteriscos significan "todos los usuarios". Puedes fijar límites por usuario, por ejemplo dándole un limit más alto a `root` aunque en el ejemplo le puse el mismo límite.

Hecho esto, la salida de

```
ulimit -Hn
```

Te dará 65535, pero `ulimit -n` seguirá diciendo `1024`.

Tienes que cerrar sesión (no en simplemente cerrar el terminal, sino desloguearte del escritorio) y al loguearte de nuevo `ulimit -n` será 65535.

Cuando yo hice este cambio (es necesario si usas webpack-dev-server, nodemon y otros simultáneamente) leí algunos tutoriales y en algunos recomiendan también editar `/etc/pam.d/common-session`

```
sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

Añadiendo

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Pero yo no tuve que hacer este último paso.

#### ¿qué le pasaría al SO si lo aumento arbitrariamente?

Puedes hacerlo pero consumirías más memoria innecesariamente. Incluso puede que en realidad sólo aplique activamente el valor de `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` ignorando un setting por encima de él. No lo he probado.

#### solo puedo utilizar ese comando una sola vez por sesión del bash, si lo intento lanzar una segunda vez me da un error de permiso

No me queda claro el por qué, pero aparentemente puedes bajar el valor sin problema, pero luego no puedes aumentarlo.

```
ffflabs@ ~/huasofoundries$ ulimit -n 4096
ffflabs@ ~/huasofoundries$ ulimit -n
4096
ffflabs@ ~/huasofoundries$ ulimit -n 2048
ffflabs@ ~/huasofoundries$ ulimit -n
2048
ffflabs@ ~/huasofoundries$ ulimit -n 4096
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
ffflabs@ ~/huasofoundries$
```

Comment: Fantástica respuesta, amenadiel